# Exact pattern match in awk

Tags: awk

I have a listA which looks like this:

```
gene1
gene2
gene11
gene22
gene23
```

I also have few tab delimited text files(*hist.txt) whose 4th column matches the genes in the list. I want to extract value of every gene in the listA from tab delimited text file

This is what I have written

```
for i in `cat listA.txt`
do
    for a in *hist.txt
    do
        fn=${a%%_*}
        cat $a | awk -v OFS="\t" -v fn="$fn" -v pattern="$i" '$4 ~ pattern{print fn,$0}' >> ${i}_out.txt
    done
done
```

My pattern match fails in awk not doing exact pattern match. The output for gene1 also include gene11.

Comment: Do a string comparison instead of a pattern match: `$4 == pattern`, although it would possibly be quicker with a single `join` command (no looping).

Comment: or `$4 ~ "^"pattern"$"` if pattern is actually a regexp and not a fixed string.  i.e. normal awk string concatenation.   so `$4 ~ "^" pattern "$"` works just as well and is, perhaps, slightly more readable.

Comment: GNU Awk 4.2.1 on Debian 10: `'$1 ~ "pattern" {print $0}'` seems to do an exact match (in this case a different var, $1).  I would be careful though given the difference between AWK versions and flavours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never use the word "pattern" in this context as it's highly ambiguous, always use "string" or "regexp", whichever you mean (see [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) for more information).

It sounds like you're trying to do a full string match but using a regexp operator (`~`) and a dynamic regexp with no boundaries (`pattern`), hence your problem.

Get rid of the surrounding shell loops and just use this 1 call to awk instead:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==FNR { genes[$1]; next }
    FNR==1 { fn=FILENAME; sub(/_.*/,"",fn) }
    $4 in genes { out=$4"_out.txt"; print fn, $0 >> out; close(out) }
' listA.txt *hist.txt
```